# Matplotlib FormatStrFormatter returns wrong values

Tags: python, matplotlib

When trying to plot a heatmap using Seaborns `sns.heatmap`function, I get wrong ticks when formatting the x-axis with `FormatStrFormatter`.  After building the required `pivot data frame`, the relevant code is:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(oi_pivot_df, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral, cbar=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_xlabel('moneyness')
ax.set_ylabel('time to maturity (years)')

fig = plt.gcf()
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Here, x varies between .5 and 96.5. Without the formatter, the x-ticks are the real range:

[image]

How do I have to change the formatter such that it returns x ticks formatted such that I only see up to the first 2 decimals, e.g. in my example below, the x axis should go from 0.92 to 1.29.

Comment: Do you get similar results with `.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)`?

Comment: Yes, using `ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:.2f}")` gives the same (wrong) result.

Answer (score 2):

Seaborn uses a FixedLocator and a FixedFormatter. If you unilaterally change the formatter, it is expected that the results become useless. If the motivation to use a Formatter is to keep the fixed labels, but change the number of decimal places, an easy solution could be to reformat the present labels.

```
def fmt(s):
    try:
        n = "{:.2f}".format(float(s))
    except:
        n = ""
    return n

ax.set_xticklabels([fmt(label.get_text()) for label in ax.get_xticklabels()])
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this triggers `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Text'`. Problem is that examples of `label` look like such: `Text(0.5,0,'-0.10536051565782628')`

Comment: The problem is that you did not provide any [mcve] for testing. I think the updated answer should work now, but is still untested.

Comment: this answer worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

I've tried:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter((ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:.3f}"))

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.3f"))
```

and many more...

No matter what I did, there was no effect
In the end, this works:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].round(3)
```

This round the values themselves to 3 decimal points.